# Trying to have JavaScript make images bigger when clicked, only works for first image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a gallery where you can click on each image to make bigger. Eventually I will stylize the gallery but for now I am just trying to get the images to work.  I copied this code from another user on Stack Overflow answering a question similar to mine, but I can't seem to make the JS work for more than just the first image.

```
#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 148, 195, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```
<img id="myImg" style="width: 200px; height: 184px;" src="ta-cards.svg" alt="Business Card Design">
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img src="ta-cards.svg" class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

      <img id="myImg" style="width: 200px; height: 184px;" src="talogos.svg" alt="Image_wallpaper">
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img src="talogos.svg" class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

```
window.onload = function() { 
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs must be unique and can't be duplicated.

Change: `id="myImg"` to `class="myImg"`

Change: `#myImg:hover` to `.myImg:hover`

New javascript, loops through the images

```
window.onload = function() { 

      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    
      var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.myImg');
      var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
imgs.forEach(function(img){
      img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
      }
    });
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
      span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
```

You need to add all images now, so

```
var fullSizeFunc = function(e) {
    model.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
document.querySelectorAll("IMG").forEach(function(i, val) {
  this.addEventListener("click", fullSizeFunc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

attribute ID is unique for each of element. And document.getElementById will select only first element that exist in the document.

```js
var lightboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.lightbox');

function lightboxModal(e) {
 const src = e.target.getAttribute('src');
 //do your modal here
}

lightboxes.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', lightboxModal);
});
```

```html
<img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/53e2d0464f5baf14f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e507440742a7ad59f49c3_640.jpg" class="lightbox" />

<img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" class="lightbox" />
```